# Best Backup Solution for SharePoint 2013 Possibly with DPM

Tags: backup, restore, file

We are planning to move our file share to SharePoint. Currently we use DPM to backup the file server, but I know the content of SharePoint is found in content databases. So my question is what is the best backup solution for file level recovery?

From what I see online, it looks like I will have to restore a backed up content database from Central Administration, and then copy the desired file I want.

This seems to be a long process just to recover a Word file.  Am I over looking something or do you have a different solution?

Thanks

Comment: PirateEric's answer IRT site collection backup is good.  Do not miss the forest for the trees, if someone deletes a document, it is in Recycle Bin.  So as long as they do not go into their settings and delete it should be there for at least 30 days.  As granular as the unattached DB restore can be, it can be a relatively quick process.

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly one option. Another option is to do individual site collection backups as well as full content db backups. This way, you can restore a single site collection to a separate farm, grab the file, then delete the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are many 3rd party tools available in the market which help you for item level recovery with less efforts.

I am not big fan of DPM we tried it but rejected. I think DocAve get a lot of market reputation for the backup&recovery tool.

For me backup is not issue but i want how quickly we restore the a file.

here are the list of available tools, you can try them.

http://www.topsharepoint.com/backup-and-recovery-tools-for-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is there. If you are only concern about single document library, then you can export it or you can save it as template(with Content) and download it in you as your backup file.